# Ordered serial numbers with leading zeroes

Tags: c#, numbers, padding, serial-number

I'm trying to generate a list of ordered serial numbers with leading zeroes like this:

```
00000000001
00000000002
00000000003
...
...
00000000101
00000000102
00000000103
...
...
00099999991
00099999992
...
...
99999999999 - END
```

My best attempt is this:

```
long fn;
for (fn = 100000000000; fn < 999999999999; fn++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fn);
}
```

I want to write all these serial numbers to a file though I don't want it to look like it counted from 1 - 999999999999, but more like serial numbers generating from 000000000000 to 999999999999.

Comment: Then why don't you start it at 0? I don't get what is the problem.

Comment: again.. i dont want it to look like this: 1..2..3..4..5... but 00001 0002 0003 0004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to pad with zeroes:

```
Console.WriteLine(fn.ToString().PadLeft(12, '0'));
```

If `fn` = 123, this will print out `000000000123`.

Answer (score 2):

Grant's answer works, my preference would be:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:00000000000}", fn);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(fn.ToString("00000000000"));
```

But really it is up to what is most readable to you...

See documentation on custom numeric string formats here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx